# Find the point of an error in Windows Phone App

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, access-violation

in my Windows Phone App I get this error:

> "The program "[4596] myProgram.exe" has ended with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."

How can I get a call stack or something other to find the place where the error occurs?
I use Visual Studio 2013 Express version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your exception object itself you have **StackTrace** or `InnerException` options.

Also, if exception is *unhandled* then `UnhandledException` handler is called automatically before app crash in `App.xaml`, you can log these things from exception object.

Advantage of using Visual Studio is you also have option to see call stack at runtime. You can get it easily by going to **Debug** menu and then choosing **Windows -> Call Stack**.